# Interaction free measurement and the Elitzur–Vaidman bomb tester, paradox solved?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I am now reading something about the interaction-free measurement, where the most famous example is the **[Elitzur–Vaidman bomb tester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester)**.

I found some discussion/debate about the 'paradox' about it, especially some discussion from the inventor Vaidman himself, where finally he went to a multi-world picture of quantum mechanics in his **[paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0102049.pdf)**, which I do not think to be the right picture.

I noticed **[in this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18617/do-interaction-free-measurements-require-a-physical-collapse-or-splitting-in-ord)** it's claimed that this is not an 'interaction free' process. But still no detailed analysis about how the interaction happens.
Meanwhile Vaidman himself insists that it's interaction free in [**a recent paper**](http://carnap.umd.edu/philphysics/vaidmanvaxjo.pdf) by checking the trace left by the pre- and post-selected photon.

Personally I do not believe there is such kind of 'interaction free' process. Even with the multi-world picture or the time travel scenario, there must be some kind of interaction (even in another world). The interaction must be hidden somewhere in this process. Also I do not think we need to bother time travel or multi-world here.

Another comment is that I think the scenario that the bomb will explode with an interaction with the photo is misleading. It makes things tricky. In fact we can just say that a 'good' bomb will block the photon in one of the arms of the interferometer.

I am wondering if there is a satisfactory explanation for it. Are the quantum information guys just satisfied with the experimental verification and simply take it as a fact which does not need more explanation? Or there is already a clear picture about it which I do not know (Anyway I did not find it :(( )?

Please let me know if there is an answer/paper on this issue.